# Passing std::future to std::async

Tags: c++, c++11, asynchronous, future

I'm trying to pass a `std::future` as an argument to `std::async` as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <future>

int t1Entry()
{
    return 1;
}

int t2Entry(std::future<int> f1)
{
    return f1.get();
}

int main()
{
    auto f1 = std::async(std::launch::async, t1Entry);
    auto f2 = std::async(std::launch::async, t2Entry, std::move(f1));
    std::cout << f2.get();
    return 1;
}
```

I'm getting the following compilation error:

> error C2280: 'std::future::future(const std::future &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function

I'm using VC++12.0 Update 4.
It seems like the compiler removes the `rvalue-reference` from the future sent to the second `std::async`.
Is there something I'm doing wrong? Or it is just a bug in the compiler?

Thanks

Comment: Works with 2015 Update 2 RC.

Comment: MSVC bug. Their `async` (and `packaged_task`, IIRC) used to use a `std::function` underneath and doesn't support move-only types.